# Vue: V-if with condition

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

in my vue application I have following code:

```
<div v-if="partner == true && kids == false" class="row">
   <input type="text" id="testInput">
</div>
```

Now when I want to try out this code snippet it does not render the input. I am pretty sure it should because the variables have the right value at this moment.

I also tried this but this does not work either:

```
<div v-if="partner && !kids" class="row">
   <input type="text" id="testInput">
<div>
```

Is the condition wrong or what is the problem with this code?

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your code or link to a sandbox? You can create vue sandbox at https://vue.new

Comment: There's nothing wrong in your condition. Problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @HanMoeHtet I already found my problem. I get my variable "kids" from localStorage and this does not return a bool, it returns a string. So v-if="partner == true && kids == 'false'" solved this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      partner: true,
      kids: false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-if="partner && !kids" class="row">
   <input type="text" id="testInput">
  </div>
</div>
```